# Past of へん and ちゃう: What's the difference between へんかった and へなんだ?

Tags: dialects, kansai-ben

Characters speaking some form of Kinki dialect are a staple in manga and it always stroke me as odd that these characters conjugated へん/ひん and ちゃう as if they were adjectives (or as if they were ない), giving forms like へんかった or ちゃうくて. This was in spite of へん/ひん seemingly coming from ぬ and ちゃう from 違う. A quick search turned up forms like へなんだ and ちごて , which make much more sense in light of this, but I have never seen it in manga. I first thought forms with かった were "wrong", but according to [https://ja.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/大阪弁/否定](https://ja.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%BC%81/%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A), forms with かった are actually used. However, it limits ちゃうかった to "若者言葉".

So how do modern speakers conjugate へん/ひん and ちゃう? Is there an age split, are both heard or only one form? Or are there even speakers who use both, with different meanings?

Comment: What is "Kinki" dialect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

〜へんかった and 〜ちゃうかった (ending with た) are the normal forms that correspond to, respectively, 〜なかった and 〜ちがった. People in some regions might say 〜へなんだ but it's not a standard form in modern 関西弁. I would assume the speaker to be an old person in a remote area.

〜へんくて and 〜ちゃうくて are recent 若者言葉, just like ちがくて in 標準語.

---

Connective forms are a bit complicated.

I say ちがって for ちゃう myself, but ちごて is also used. It's a reduced form of ちごうて, which sounds more こてこて.

When へん is connected directly to the ない-stem of a verb, its connective form is 〜んで. For example, 食べへん (meaning 食べない) becomes 食べんで. When it is connected to a て-form, I would say 〜なくて is more common. So the connective form of 食べてへん (meaning 食べていない) is 食べてなくて.

〜へんかって doesn't particularly sound like 若者言葉 when it's part of 〜ても, though. 食べへんかっても sounds fine for 食べなくても. You can also say 食べんでも.

〜へんかって can also occur when followed by the explanatory ん. For example, you can say 食べへんかってん for 食べなかったんだ（よ）.