Meaning of てしまう in this sentence
A group of friends are unsure on which way to continue from an intersection and one says:
「多分左ちゃうかな」
The subtitles translates this as "Let's go left from here" but I think that some nuance is lost in translation.
Could てしまう be interpreted as a perfective article, similar to the Chinese "了"? As a native Chinese speaker, that would make it much easier to understand.
Following this interpretation, I'd say it brings a kind of conclusive air to the question. Is this correct?

This has nothing to do with しまう. It's a dialectal contracted form of 違う.

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/103693/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/102200/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86570/9831

It can't be てしまう because the て of てしまう would be part of the inflection of a verb (which 左 isn't).
